# Open a .js code and write the code in HTML of Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

When I apply any third party gadget in my Blogger, what happens most of the time is that they provide a link of .js code along with some html code. For example, a gadget that lists all of my posts, contains this html:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<a href="http://www.payzeroworld.com/p/all-games.html"><b><span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;">Switch to Alphabetic View =&gt;</span></b></a></div>
</div>
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<script src="http://techieopus.googlecode.com/files/blogger_toc.js"type="text/javascript"></script><br />
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?max-results=9999&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=loadtoc" type="text/javascript"></script>
<br />
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<div style="text-align: center;">
<br /></div>`
```

etc etc.....

Now if you give a close look there is a `"http://techieopus.googlecode.com/files/blogger_toc.js"` in the above code. If I go to the link, I can see the JavaScript code.

I don't want to use the 'link' of that JavaScript in my HTML. Rather, I want to use the 'actual' code. How can I do that?

Comment: why do you care what source of script file is?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but either way, that `Javascript` is heavily obfuscated anyway, so you would need to decypt it.

Comment: @charlietfl: That will give me the freedom of editing the js code and use it,the way I want.

Comment: @NickR:I want to open this code - [http://techieopus.googlecode.com/files/blogger_toc.js](http://techieopus.googlecode.com/files/blogger_toc.js) , edit the code, then reuse it in my html.

Comment: copy it to your site then if license allows it

Comment: Again - the code is `obfuscated`, you need to `decrypt` it. The code is under the `GNU GPL v3` license, so should be OK.

Comment: @charlietfl:  I know that I have to copy it. Nut, where exactly I have to paste it?

Comment: You need to host the file somewhere...

Comment: follow blogger instructions for adding script

Comment: @NickR: ok, forget about this particular code. If a code can be viewed finely(from browser,or, notepad) then how can I paste that code in my html?

Comment: @NickR: The point is again coming towards use a `link` of js code, rather than the `actual` code.  I want to get rid of this

Comment: @charlietfl: Can you refer me to that link?

Comment: can always paste it directly into a script tag....google `host javascript blogger` ...really not difficult to search

Comment: @charlietfl: like this `<script my java code here </script><br />` ?

Comment: @charlietfl: ok I will search for it.